# How to install NPM behind authentication proxy on Windows?

Tags: node.js, proxy

I need to run the latest version of Node and NPM on Windows. I installed Node 0.5.8 and downloaded the sources of NPM from GitHub. The steps I followed to install NPM were listed on its GitHub site but I have a problem running the following command:

```
node cli.js install npm -gf
```

but it fails with the following error message:

```
Error: connect UNKNOWN
at errnoException (net_uv.js:566:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net_uv.js:557:18)

System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
command "...\\Node\\bin\\node.exe" "...\\npm\\cli.js" "install" "npm" "-gf"
cwd ...\npm
node -v v0.5.8
npm -v 1.0.94
code UNKNOWN
```

I think that this is a problem because I need authentication at my proxy to connect to the Internet. But I found no way to tell the installer to use my credentials for login. Is there a possibility to provide my proxy IP and login information to npm installation maybe via command-line arguments?

I can provide the full log (but seems to have no more relevant information) using pastebin if needed.

Comment: A little trick, if the user name contains the domain\user notation substitute the backslash with the http escape code (%5C)

Comment: @layos Thank you sooooo much. If this was reddit, I'd give you gold.

Answer (score 40):

`set http_proxy` worked really well for me but I had to enter it in every time I opened the command prompt. So I had to combine multiple answers and now mine is permanent.

My sequence went as follows:

- Go to `C:\Users\YourUserName`
- Create a file named `.npmrc`
- Inside that file type the following (if you are on an AD domain):

`proxy = http://domain\\username:password@ip:port`

- Or use this is you are NOT on an AD domain:

`proxy = http://username:password@ip:port`

- Save the File
- Open a command prompt and try to use `npm`

Others have had extra success with the following extra command:

`strict-ssl = false`

*You should be able to use an IP address or the URL to the proxy in place of "IP" above.

Your proxy string may need to be tweaked a bit, but this made it so that I didn't have to add this every single time.

Cheers

Comment: Heads up, if your password contains "@" npm won't parse your proxy setting correctly.  A potential workaround is to put a bogus username:password in the npm config, and use a local proxy (like fiddler) to modify the request's Proxy-Authorization header to have the correct username:password.  Keep in mind the the username:password stored in Proxy-Authorization is base64 encoded.

Comment: Got mine to work with: `proxy = http://ip:port/
https-proxy = http://ip:port/
registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl = false`

Comment: didnt get mine to work with username:password

Comment: Hey, I tried using `domain\\user:password@urltoproxy:port` however, when I run `npm install` the option changes to `domain/user:password@urltoproxy:port` So how do I work around this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as @JacobSchneider, on my .npmrc:
`-ssl=false
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
proxy=http://domain\\username:password#@proxy.url:8080`

then when I get setting from config with `npm config get proxy`:
`http://domain/username:password#@proxy.url:8080`

**note** that the escaped backslash '\\' changes to  a forward slash '/'

Answer (score 10):

Maybe setting an environment variable will work for you:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@server.url:port
```

(In my case, this solves the "connect UNKNOWN", but I get a completely different "socket hang up" error.  I also tried setting the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable, but got the same result.)

Comment: I tried setting the environment variable and also tried passing --proxy http://user:pass@server.url:port to the command but now I alway get ECONNREFUSED.. Do I need to specify my AD domain for the proxy login?

Comment: @Tobias try `set HTTP_PROXY=http://domain\user:pass@server.url:port`

Answer (score 8):

I had this identical issue and here's what I did to make this work:

- Go to: `C:\Users\YourUserName`
- Create a file named `.npmrc`
- And it's entry will read:

  ```
  registry = http://registry.npmjs.org
  ```
- Try the command `node cli.js install npm -gf` again.

Comment: I created the file with the contents you mentioned but still getting the connect UNKNOWN error :(

Comment: Cheers for this. Did a "npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org" to get around the https:// and all is well on my windows setup.

Comment: if somebody gets the ETIMEOUT message add proxy setting with `node config set proxy http://username:password@server:port`

Comment: What worked for me was creating the `~/.npmrc` file like above, which tells npm to use the `http://` registry instead of `https://`, and then setting my `http_proxy` environment variable to `http://myusername:mypassword@proxy.company.com:1234`

Comment: Heads up, if your password contains "@" npm won't parse your proxy setting correctly.  A potential workaround is to put a bogus username:password in the npm config, and use a local proxy (like fiddler) to modify the request's Proxy-Authorization header to have the correct username:password.  Keep in mind the the username:password stored in Proxy-Authorization is base64 encoded.

Comment: In my case, switching the registry from `https://` to `http://` resolved it

Answer (score 5):

After some research, I could use it in this way:

1. Install NTLM Authorization Proxy Server or another proxy server for NTLM, like Cntlm. Personally, I prefer the python server, because I can tinker with it, and performance is not a problem.
2. Set up the configuration; note that in my case, I had to enable both LM and NT mode, and I would suspect it being the normal case, nowadays.
3. Set http_proxy and https_proxy environment variable to point to your local proxy:

   set http_proxy="localhost:5865"
   set https_proxy="localhost:5865"
4. npm should work now, of course it should be executed from a shell where the above environment variables are defined.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me.

On Windows 7:

```
npm config set proxy xxhttp://username:password@proxyhost:port#
```

This should create a file named `.npmrc` in the `C:/users/<username>` folder.

Answer (score 3):

Type this in command line:

`npm set proxy http://user:pass@ip:port`

`npm set https-proxy http://user:pass@ip:port`

DONT FORGET TO INCLUDE **HTTP://** before your username. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Each one of the above answers needs the user to write her password in a text file, or in an environ ment variable.

Personally I didn't like a solution like these, for their insecure approach. So I tried to write an application which injects the Kerberos token of the current user in the exchanges between the client (npm, bower, git) and the proxy. That said, Active Directory is just a proprietary implementation of Kerberos.

I use this software everyday, on a Windows 8.1 host. You can find the code (golang) and the first release binaries on https://github.com/nilleb/authentication-proxy.

Answer (score 2):

This issue resolved for me after creating the *.npmrc* file as above, and then running the adduser command and following cmd prompts.

```
npm adduser
```

Run the following comman to see if you have an authorised username:

```
npm whoami
```

Answer (score 2):

At least in Windows, it works for me with the following setting:

```
proxy=http://domain%5Cusername:password@proxy_ip:port
```

i.e., (1) use `%5C` instead of `\` (as suggested elsewhere) and (2) use the IP address instead of the local machine name for the proxy server.

Comment: This is correct - the domain+username and the password need to be URL encoded separately. E.g. if you have # in your password, replace it with %23

Answer (score 1):

All three things worked for me in .npmrc

```
proxy = http://unam:pwd@host:port
https-proxy = http://unam:pwd@host:port
registry = http://registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get the proxy host and port from your server administrator or support.

After that set up

```
npm config set http_proxy http://username:password@proxyofmycomp.com:itsport
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxyofmycomp.com:itsport
```

If there any special character in password try with % urlencode. Eg:- pound(hash) shuold be replaced by %23.

Comment: Which versions does your answer apply to given that the question was asked over 3 years ago?

Comment: I belive it does not matter. I found the solution to this problem after trying a lot and never knew that my password was making issue.In order to make it perfect anwser no matter question was asked even before ten years :)...

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me is the following:

npm config set http_proxy http://*username*:*password*@*host/IP*:*port*

npm config set proxy http://*username*:*password*@*host/IP*:*port*

replace the parameters with the values, in my case

**username**:   (empty)

**password**:   (empty)

**host/IP** : 192.36.36.110

**port**    : 8080

so My commands are

npm config set http_proxy http://:@192.36.36.110:8080

npm config set proxy http://:@192.36.36.110:8080

Answer (score 0):

CNTLM didn't work for me. I tried all possible combinations. NPM was giving Authentication error. Fiddler came for rescue and saved my time. It is easy to install and configure. Set Fiddler Rule to Automatically Authenticated.In .npmrc set these

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org
proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
https-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
http-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888
strict-ssl=false
```

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was as follows:

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org
proxy=http://<url.pac>
https-proxy=http://<url.pac>
http-proxy=http://<url.pac>
strict-ssl=false
```

I did not have to enter any usernames or passwords, simply the PAC file url.